# How to display the ViewController depending on the result

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm starting with iOS, I have a doubt, about, Which is the best practise, when we have a ViewController, and we have another 4 viewcontrolers, and depending of the result we want to open one view according with the result?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps there can be many approaches to achieve what you have stated

Comment: Please show us some code to explain what the issue is. Your question is incredibly vague. I don't understand what it is exactly your having trouble with

Comment: please provide some more info on the exact issue... with this it's not possible to give proper advice!

Comment: Is not a issue, is a question about the best practise to implement that, I'm starting to develop in iOS and I want to learn the best implementation for that, my initial idea was the idea from MEDA in the comment below, with switch, but my question want to know if exist another native control in storyborard, like navigatorController..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your concern because you can't simply hook segues to buttons or navigation items to control the flow of your app if you don't know at design time what path the user will take.

The typical practice is to go ahead and create the segues anyway (*push* segues for navigation controllers), but don't hook them up to a control on the sending side (hook them right up to the sending view controller). Then, call UIViewController's [`performSegueWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) from the sending view controller.

Setup any properties on the destination view controller in [`prepareForSegue:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) from the sending view controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcus Adams this is exactly the response for my question. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic of control flow. You design logic based on the result.

Example:

```
switch (result) {
    case 0:
        //go to viewController1
        break;
    case 1:
        //go to viewController2
        break;
    default:
        //go to defaultViewcontroller
        break;
}
```

You can use, `switch case`, `if/else` or `ternary operator` to decide the flow of your app.

Comment: Thanks meda, this is helpful too.

Comment: @JOANA_Batista your welcome, Marcus gave you a good clue to the common practice, they arent many ways to do it anyway you know